# Save shipping address after discount code applying

Tags: magento2, discount, shipping-address

All previously filled information with shipping address is deleted, if I use coupone code in my cart summary block.

As you can see State and Zip code are chosen.

[image]

And then, if I apply discount code all information are gone.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you try using js register?

Comment: Have you check consol or log files?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya is this a bug? What should I find in a log files? Console is clean

Comment: @SohelRana Can you please give me more info? What do you mean?